# Convert character to index for jump table in C

Tags: c

I have to implement a calculator in C. It gets 3 arguments (int, char, int) where char can be +, -, x or /. I must implement the calculator with a jump table which points to the 4 corresponding functions (e.g. plus(int x, int y)). I know how to access the functions in the jump table but I must not use a switch statement or multiple 'if's to choose the appropriate function. I got a hint, that there is a function in string.h, which can be used to solve this problem.

tl;dr: How to convert 4 different chars into an index from 0 to 3 with a function from string.h without using switch or if?

Comment: What is wrong with using a `switch`? Seems the most straightforward solution

Comment: It is a task for school and the task says: "No switch or if"

Comment: these kind of assignments are super dumb... they obviously want you to discover something fundamental about the language, but it isn't something that you are going to use... because you wont be using a jump table with some esoteric addressing scheme... you will be using a friggin switch and functions... grr

Comment: @GradyPlayer Parsers use function tables like this all the time, particularly in C.  More often, the table entry includes more about index value (an enum instance, typically), but that doesn't change the principal that the "jump" is done by function pointer in an array entry, not by switch on a constant.

Comment: @MikeHousky a function table is more than a jump table... in that the function predicate takes care of the stack manipulation for you. Though I am sure you could colloquially mix the two terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [`strchr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) function.

```
// Call with oper = '+', '-', 'x' or '/'.
unsigned int op_to_index(char ch)
{
  const char *ops = "+-x/";

  return strchr(ops, op) - ops;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that should do the trick. Edit: Works like a charm!

Comment: My bad, I took it for another function (trying to remember C these days). +1.

Comment: But this is also the same thing as the switch statement... with some extra function calls and arithmetic for overhead.

Comment: @Lundin Of course it's silly, but the question was silly to begin with so it's expected that the solutions will be too. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array and then search through it for the corresponding character using a for loop. But machine code-wise, this is *exactly* the same thing as a switch, so it doesn't make much sense.

```
const char OPERATORS[] = 
{
  '+', 
  '-', 
  '*', 
  '/'
};

bool calculate (int x, char symbol, int y)
{
  bool valid = false;
  int i;

  for(i=0; i<sizeof(OPERATORS); i++)
  {
    if(symbol == OPERATORS[i])
    {
      valid = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if(!valid)
  {
    return valid;
  }

  operator_func[i](x, y);

  return valid;
}
```

(The only place where the above would be more efficient than a switch, would be when there is a whole lot of operators and you store them in a sorted order (by ASCII value). Then you can do a binary search instead of the linear for loop. But for this few operators, the overhead of such search function calls will only slow the program down.)

---

The advantage of the above is that you can merge it with the function pointer table and get a more object-oriented design:

```
// the above rewritten with a bit of OO design:

typedef void(*operator_func_t)(int , int y);

typedef struct
{
  char             symbol;
  operator_func_t  func;
} operator_t;

...

void add (int x, int y);
void subtract (int x, int y);

...


operator_t OPERATORS[] = 
{
  {'+', &add},
  {'-', &subtract},
  {'*', &multiply},
  {'/', &divide}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What about your own jump table?

```
typedef int (*calcfun)(int,int) ;

int plus(int,int) ;
int minus(int,int) ;
int mul(int,int) ;
int div(int,int) ;

calcfun fun[256] ;

void init(void)
{
    fun[(int) '+'] = plus ;
    fun[(int) '-'] = minus ;
    fun[(int) '*'] = mul ;
    fun[(int) '/'] = div ;
}

void (void)
{
     init() ;
     ...
     if (fun[symbol]) 
          result = fun[symbol](x,y) ;
     else printf("invalid op '%c'\n",symbol) ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

here is a hint...

I assume you could have an array with as many elements as the ascii value for '+', '-', 'x', or '/' whichever is highest...